# Why does Eclipse internal browser stop the execution on console?

Tags: ajax, eclipse, servlets

This is more of a theoretical question about eclipse internal browser behavior. I am working on a web application in eclipse, in which I send an AJAX request from JSP to a servlet. There are few standard output expressions in servlet that show up on console and then servlet send the response back in AJAX success function. I just alert success message in success function. Now when I run this application on Firefox.

The execution happens this way as I expect.

1. Data is sent from jsp to servlet.
2. Servlet prints the standard output on console.
3. Response is sent back to the AJAX call.
4. Browser shows the success alert.

while in Eclipse internal browser:

1. Data is sent from jsp to servlet.
   (Nothing happens in the console.)
2. Response is sent back to ajax success function.
3. An alert box shows up.
4. I click the alert to go away...
5. Then it prints the standard outputs in the Eclipse console which I was expecting in the 2nd step.

Why does Eclipse browser stop the console from printing until the AJAX request is complete while other browsers don't? Is this the expected behavior of Eclipse browser or not?